# HDFS Files sort in Giga byte

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to automate the HDFS user space utilisation mail.

Everything went correct exept the sorting of the files in gb.when i tried with bytes it is giving the correct result but in other it is not coming the expected output.

please help me the get the correct output.

i ll provide the script which i run in bytes as well as human readable -h in hdfs file system.

```
#!/bin/bash

#getting the current hdfs percentage in numeric value

CURRENT=$(hdfs dfs -df -h/ | grep / | awk '{ print $8}' | sed 's/%//g')

#current hdfs space utilisation
DiskFile=$(hdfs dfs -df -h)

HdfsReport=$(hdfs dfsadmin -report)

Diskuse=$(hdfs dfs -du  /user | sort -nr | head -10)

#To get results GB i have provided $(hdfs dfs -du -h  /user | sort -r | head -10)
THRESHOLD=70
Critical=90

if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then

mail -s 'HDFS Usage Housekeeping required' @abc.com, @abc.com << EOF
HDFS usage in Cluster is above the threshold please run the clean-up scripts asap. Used: $CURRENT%

Current disk utilization report is
$DiskFile

Please find the Utilisation report of top ten users consuming the cluster

$Diskuse




EOF
fi

if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$Critical" ] ; then

mail -s 'HDFS Admin Report' yy@abc.com, yyy@abc.com << EOF
HDFS usage in Cluster is above critical storage, please Find the Cluster report below

$HdfsReport



EOF
fi
```

Comment: i got the script to sort in GB or TB



Diskuse=$(hdfs dfs -du /user |sort -n -r | awk '{print $1/1099511531398.98," TB ", 

$2/1099511531398.98," TB ", $3}'| head -10)


For displaying the sorted values in GB please use 1073741824 instead of 1099511531398.98

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "human" format in sort command instead , eg `sort -rh`
I don't have dfs but the below example command is listing/sorting the 10 biggest directories in my current dir :

```
du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
```

Comment: The above command is working fine in linux, But when it comes to hdfs it is not working.
 I tried with sort -rh , I am not getting the expecting output.

Diskuse=$(hdfs dfs -du -hsx /user | sort -rh | head -10)

output which i am getting is 

870.6 M  1.7 G    /user/sxs609
704      1.4 K    /user/bxr125
654.4 M  1.3 G    /user/rxs325
647.0 M  1.3 G    /user/axk255
634.6 G  1.2 T    /user/d360
583.4 M  1.1 G    /user/oozie
497.2 G  994.4 G  /user/d360npi_cia
483.1 M  966.2 M  /user/nxk149
459.1 K  918.2 K  /user/nxk148
451.4 M  902.7 M  /user/rxt113

which not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try numfmt, like this:

```
hdfs dfs -du -s  /user/* | numfmt --to iec
```